# how to send array to servlet from $.ajax method?

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

i want to pass array to servlet as request parameter, how to send it

```
   $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyServlet",
              data: params,
              success: function(data){ 
                            closeMe();                                               
                      },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                            alert(errorThrown)
                     }
   });  // end of $.ajax()


 $("#savebtn").click(function(e) {
     var username = $("#username").val();
     var password = $("#password").val();
     var checkIP  = $("#chkIP").is(":checked");

      var params = {
                    action : 'add',
                    username : username,
                    password : password,
                    checkIP : checkIP,
                };
     if(checkIP){
                   var ipList = $("#ipaddress").val();
                   var ip = ipList.split(',');
                   params['ipList'] = ip
                }
     });
```

html

```
        <tr>
            <td>Check IP</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkIP" id="chkIP"></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>IP List</td>
            <td><textarea id="ipaddress"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
```

for e.g id user enter `122.112.122.45,122.112.122.46,....N`   in textarea then how to retrive it in servlet and store in db ?

Comment: you might split your ipaddresses inside your servlet if you have difficulties doing so in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably split it at the client side to validate that each IP is valid.

But since everything that is sent over HTTP to the Servlet is 'flattened', i.e. from `Object` to `String` representation, it will be simpler to sent the IPs in String format e.g. `122.112.122.45,122.112.122.46,....N` over and split it in the Java Servlet.

```
public String[] splitIps(final String ipsRawString){
  return ipsRawString.split(",");
}
```